# Regexp for string stating with a + and having numbers only

Tags: regex

I have the following regex for a string which starts by a + and having numbers only:

```
PatternArticleNumber = $"^(\\+)[0-9]*";
```

However this allows strings like :

> +454545454+4545454

This should not be allowed.  Only the 1st character should be a +, others numbers only.
Any idea what may be wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably workaround this problem by just adding an ending anchor to your regex, i.e. use this:

```
PatternArticleNumber = $"^(\\+)[0-9]*$";
```

### Demo

The problem with your current pattern is that the ending is open.  So, the string `+454545454+4545454` might appear to be a match.  In fact, that *entire* string is not a match, but the engine might match the first portion, before the second `+`, and report a match.